# loop for in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have to iterate through an object of objects with a for-loop.

I want to start the iteration at an index in the middle of the array - I don't want to start with the first element.

```
for(var i=elementId in this._uiElementsData)
    {
        cont++;

        if(cont == 1)
        {
            var element = this._uiElementsData[i];              
            uno = element.uiElementIndex;
        }
        else if(cont == 2)
        {
            var element = this._uiElementsData[i];              
            dos = element.uiElementIndex;
        }
        else if(cont > 2)   break;      

    }
```

I tried that, but it starts with the first element of the array...
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just start at the half way index, like this?

```
var halfWay = (this._uiElementsData.length / 2);

// if 6 elements in the array / 2 = 3, start at 3rd element
for(var i= halfWay; i < this._uiElementsData.length, i++)
{
    var index = (i + 1); // index is zero based for the array, so plus 1
    var element = this._uiElementsData[i]; // 3rd item in the array... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = desired_start_point;
uno = this._uiElementsData[n].uiElementIndex;
dos = this._uiElementsData[n+1].uiElementIndex;
tres = ..
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want a `for..in` loop here, just a `for` loop

```
// start at index 1
for (var i = 1; i < this._uiElementsData.length; ++i) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: "I have to iterate in an array of objects" => the data structure is `[{}, {}, {}, ...]`, you shouldn't loop over this with `for..in`.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't explained well...I really have a object of objects...if like an array, but not really an array...so I can't use length ... :(

Comment: @Daniel - An _Object_ which is not/does not inherit from _Array_ does not have a defined "order" for it's keys, so the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @alex23 I never `var` inside a loop, I'd either `var i; for (i = ...` or I'd `var i = ...; for (; ...`.

Comment: @alex23 It extends from how I only use one `var` for a whole _Function_; it means you can look in one place for all variables that have been given scope meaning you only `var` each variable name once, and (by putting it at the top) don't have to worry as much about how `var` is hoisted, which may cause unexpected _undefined_ or scope capturing. Having a `var` inside a loop would mean I'd `var` for each loop, or that my loops couldn't be re-ordered without changing them. It really just comes down to a style of writing code.

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) continue;
i; // 2`